# How to find the interval of concavity and point of inflection

Tags: calculus, derivatives

\begin{equation*}
y=( x-5)( x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{equation*}

I have already differentiated and it becomes

$y'=\frac{4x-8}{3( x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$

$y''= \frac{4x+4}{9( x-1)^{\frac{5}{3}}}$

I think there is one point of inflection that is undefined but I am not sure how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental definition for point of inflection 'is a point on a smooth plane curve at which the curvature $(\kappa)$ changes sign'. If something which is varying continuously is changing sign then it must take the value 'zero' in the process. Since the curvature $(\kappa)$ is proportional to $y''$ hence the condition $y''=0$ also implies that $\kappa=0$ at that point. But this approximation is correct only when $y''$ is defined at that point, can be $0$ but not $\infty$.

For the function you have, there is no doubt that at $x=-1$ there is an inflection point as $y''(-1)=0$. But for $x=1$ the $y''$ is undefined. There you should try to use the complete defination of curvature $\kappa$. i.e,

\begin{align}
\kappa=\frac{|y^{''}|}{(1+{y^{'}}^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \tag{1}
\end{align}
If you substitute $y'$ and $y''$ that you have already have derived in eq (1), you will get,
\begin{align}
\kappa=\frac{4(x+1)}{\left[9(x-1)^{4/3} + 16(x-2)^{2}\right]^{3/2}}*3(x-1)^{1/3} \tag{2}
\end{align}
You can see $\kappa(x=1)=0$ it's no more undefined. Hence the point $x=1$ is also an inflection point.

Things will become more clear if you plot the function:

[image: Function plot with range -120 to 5]

I have put a red straight line to show the curvature in the $x<-1$ range. You can see the curve changes the sign of curvature three times.

\begin{align}
 x<-1: & \text{concave upward} \\
 -1<x<1: & \text{concave downward} \\
 x>1: & \text{concave upward}
\end{align}
Hence there will be two inflection points.

See the curve's behavior in the close range of it's inflection points.
[image: x range -2 to 5]

Answer (score 0):

The points of inflection are those places, where either $f"(x)=0$ or $f"(x)$ is undefined, but f(x) MUST be defined for all these points.

For your equation, the POSSIBLE points of inflection are $x=-1$ or $x=1$.
(from the second derivative)

Check - does the function exist at these points? If so, then you have your points of inflection.

Comment: Hi, may I know how can I get x=1? I just able to get x=-1 (from 4x+4=0)

Comment: $f"(x)$ may be UNDEFINED. That is, the possiblity of the denominator being zero should also be considered.